# XML file as query data for SQL with ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, xml, database, coldfusion

I am developing a web application right now, where the user interacts with desktop software that exports files as XML.

I was curious if there was a way to take the data from the XML file and insert that data into a mySQL database using ColdFusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can, ColdFusion provides powerful tools for handling XML.

Typically you'll need to parse XML file into the XML document object with [XmlParse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e90.html) and search through it using XPath language with [XmlSearch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78e8.html). Fetched data you can easily use for inserting into the database or any other manipulations.

Please note that there are more useful [XML functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-69fb.html) present, for example you may be interested in validation XML before parsing it.

If you'll need help for specific situations -- please extend your question or ask another one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with XML documents that fit into memory when parsed, @Sergii's answer is the right way to go. On the other hand, XML being verbose as it is, and ColdFusion's using a DOM XML parser, can easily lead to Out of Memory errors.

In that situation, given MySQL and ColdFusion, I see two alternative paths. One is exporting the data from the desktop application as CSV, if possible. Then use MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), which you can call from ColdFusion to import the data. This is probably the fastest performance.

If you cannot change the desktop application's export format, consider using a [Java StAX parser](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/stax/) instead. [See my answer from another question for an example of how to do this with ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566059/xslt-conversion-creating-new-qnames-from-elements/4572094#4572094). This has the advantage of only pulling in part of the XML document into memory at any given time, but is somewhat more difficult to work with than a DOM parser. As such you will not get OOM errors.

Note, there is a third type of parser available as well from Java - [SAX](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) - that has the same quality as a StAX parser of not loading the whole document into memory. However, it's a more difficult approach IMO to work with, thus the StAX recommendation.